# Passing different types of arrays to an UDF function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that show the content of an array in excel sheet. The header of my function looks like this :

`Public Sub afficher_signal(ByRef signal() As Integer, ByVal nb_ligne As Integer)`

The probleme is that sometime I want to use it to display an Integer array and sometimes, its a double array i want to display. Is there a way to change the 
`ByRef signal() as Integer`
by something that would accept any kind of array ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Just `ByRef signal()` (no `As ...`) should do it.

Comment: Sorry - drop the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Public Sub afficher_signal(ByRef signal() As Integer, ByVal nb_ligne As Integer)
```

with

```
Public Sub afficher_signal(ByRef signal, ByVal nb_ligne As Integer)
```

or

```
Public Sub afficher_signal(ByRef signal as Variant, ByVal nb_ligne As Integer)
```

The  below demonstrates a sample use of the `afficher_signal`

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array(1, "yo", 3, 10 Mod 2, 5.25)
    afficher_signal arr, 0
    afficher_signal2 arr, 0
End Sub

Public Sub afficher_signal(ByRef signal As Variant, ByVal nb_ligne As Integer)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(signal) To UBound(signal)
        Debug.Print signal(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub afficher_signal2(ByRef signal, ByVal nb_ligne As Integer)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(signal) To UBound(signal)
        Debug.Print signal(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```